# How to use AudioRecord.SetRecordPositionUpdateLister in Xamarin?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-audiorecord

I'm trying to setup a listener to an audio stream. Here is the (shortened) source:

```
class AndroidAudioDriver : AudioRecord.IOnRecordPositionUpdateListener
{
    private AudioRecord _recorder;
    private byte[] _audioData;
    private int _bufferSize;
    private Sensor _sensor;

    public AndroidAudioDriver(Sensor sensor, int desiredSampleRate)
    {
        _recorder = new AudioRecord(AudioSource.Mic, SampleRate, ChannelIn.Mono, Encoding.PcmFloat, _bufferSize);
        _recorder.SetRecordPositionUpdateListener(this);
        _recorder.SetPositionNotificationPeriod(_bufferSize / 2);
    }

    public void OnMarkerReached(AudioRecord recorder)
    {
        //not used
    }

    public void OnPeriodicNotification(AudioRecord recorder)
    {
        var count = _recorder.Read(_audioData, 0, _bufferSize / 2);
        var floats = DataConversion.ConvertBytesToFloatsBigEndian(_audioData.Take(count).ToArray());
        NewAudio(_sensor, floats);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

My class inherits the IOnRecordPositionUpdateListener. `_recorder.SetRecordPositionUpdateListener` expects this type as argument, but at runtime I'm getting a *"System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid"*. I don't understand how to set the update listener in Xamarin, the Android examples are very different and don't seem to apply the same logic.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My class inherits the IOnRecordPositionUpdateListener

You are *implementing* the interface, but you need to *inherit* from `Java.Lang.Object`.

Once you do that, make the class public for the ACW (Android Callable Wrapper) that will be generated.

Remove the `public void Dispose()` as `Java.Lang.Object` implements that. If need be, `override` it and handle disposing any of your resources, like the hardware's `Sensor` object.

```
public class AndroidAudioDriver : Java.Lang.Object, AudioRecord.IOnRecordPositionUpdateListener
{

   ~~~
}
```

Comment: Perfect thanks. Can I ask where you found this information? This isn't mentioned in the Xamarin documentation anywhere that I can find...

Comment: @Lukeyb Any object that needs to be used within the Android Java VM (ART or Dalvik) needs a Java (JNI-based) wrapper so it can call back into the Mono runtime and be redirected to your C#/F# managed code. Check out the Interface section of: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/java_integration_overview/android_callable_wrappers/